# Ramda how to filter array of objects where some key contains

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I would like to filter an array of objects if one of the keys contains so string.
given the data:

```
const data = [
    {id: 1, value: 'abs', x: 'ee'}
    {id: 2, value: 'ws', x: '21'},
    {id: 3, value: 'asd', x: 'as'},        
    {id: 4, value: 'x', x: 'ee'},
]
```

I want to be able given the sting or number to filter this array if some value contains the given input
if i get `w` i want to be able to get only the second element
if i get `a` i want to be able to get the first and third element and so on.

thanks ahead

Comment: Is using Ramda necessary? It would be trivial in standard JS

Comment: @CertainPerformance pref to.. but how trivial in standart js?

Comment: @baao this is not what im looking for because you are filtering only be the key `value` i want to be able to filter by all keys

Comment: Changed the comment accordingly, please make sure to specify your requirements in the question when you ask. Your question reads _if some value_ which was confusing as your objects contain a property `value`

Comment: `data.filter(e => Object.values(e).some(v => String(v).includes('a')))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
const data = [
  {id: 1, value: 'abs', x: 'ee'},
  {id: 2, value: 'ws', x: '21'},
  {id: 3, value: 'asd', x: 'as'},        
  {id: 4, value: 'x', x: 'ee'}
]

const customFilter = val => R.filter(R.compose(R.any(R.contains(val)),R.values))

console.log(customFilter('a')(data))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```